# How can I capture Java compiler errors into a file?

Tags: java, javac, io-redirection

I compiled a Java program as

```
javac t1.java > a
```

in order to redirect the error messages to file `a`. But `a` doesn't have the error contents (they still appear in the terminal). The command is executed from Linux command prompt.

The contents of t1.java is as:

```
class t1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.printn("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

So now there is an error, i.e. `println` is written as `printn`.

How can I capture this error message in file `a`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try redirecting the `stderr`:

```
javac t1.java 2> error_file
```

Answer (score 2):

`> foo` implies `1> foo` where `1` is the stdout stream.

In bash, if you want to redirect the stderr stream, use `2> foo`

The standard Unix fileno's are 0 - stdin, 1 - stdout, 2 - stderr.