# How to store the result of compilation (using javac) to a text file?

Tags: stdout, javac, stderr

I want to compile a Hello World program. I use `javac Hello_World.java`. However in cmd terminal window, it shows `"semicolon is missing" compilation error.`

How do I store this compilation error into a text file?  Or even a string will do. How do I "catch" this error? I tried

```
javac filename.java 2 > textfile.txt
```

But javac still prints stderr and stdout to screen.

Comment: Compile errors probably go to stderr, so redirecting it makes sense. Either way, redirecting stdout/stderr should be sufficient.

Comment: If you're using Windows, try looking at this article
https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: On the mac terminal, that would work. The suggested link above is also good

Comment: Please use search term "shell redirection". Also read up on "stdout" and "stderr".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I capture Java compiler errors into a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665589/how-can-i-capture-java-compiler-errors-into-a-file)

Comment: The result of compilation is not text, so you can not store it in a text file.  The error messages of compilation are text.  That's what you want to store in a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the space between 2 and >

```
javac filename.java 2> textfile.txt
```

Another way is by redirecting stderr into stdout:

```
javac filename.java > textfile.txt 2>&1
```

More info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout

Answer (score 0):

-verbose is what you´re looking for. It will show the logs of the compiler, then you put the output in a file.

javac XXX -verbose > textfile.txt