# How to display the result of compilation of a .java file stored in a .txt file immediatly on execution?

Tags: java, file, processbuilder

Suppose I have a Program A. From within this Program A, I am compiling Program B and storing the result in a file "Error.txt". Code is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class CompileFile
{   
    public void Compile() throws IOException
    {
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "javac *.java 2> Error.txt");

        p.start();
    }   
}
```

Now, I have to display the contents of "Error.txt" from within Program A. I am using simple FileReader + BufferedReader. However, I am not getting any output.

The Error.txt file does contain the compilation errors/result, but this happens **AFTER** Program A finishes execution. It remains empty while Program A is being executed. Hence, I get no result **the first time** I run Program A.

How do I resolve this problem ?

NOTE: This is a follow-up to my last question: [How to store the result of compilation (using javac) to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768021/how-to-store-the-result-of-compilation-using-javac-to-a-text-file) . You can check it for reference if you must.

Comment: NOTE: the class CompileFile is not the Program A in reference. I simply create an object of class CompileFile from within Program A.

Comment: Who upvoted this question? This would take a minute or two to figure out if you did a little bit of research. You might want to start with the javadocs of the `Process` class. This is, of course, only if you absolutely _need_ to write it to a file first. If not, you should just read the output of the command directly and write it to `System.out`

Comment: Would `"cmd.exe", "/C", "javac *.java 2> Error.txt; cat Error.txt"` be a valid way of doing it?

Comment: @patrick-hainge No. Because the output of the cat command would go into a buffer that OP does not appear to be doing anything with.

Comment: @AbhikBiswas You can go through this tutorial: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/

Comment: did u looked at javac programming interface? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html look for PROGRAMMATIC INTERFACE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `waitFor` after you start your `ProcessBuilder` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", 
            "javac path\\of_your_file\\file.java 2> path\\of_your_file\\Error.txt");
    Process process = p.start();
    process.waitFor();//wait until your process finished 

    Scanner in = new Scanner(Paths.get("path\\of_your_file\\Error.txt"));
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```